# Servlet init-parameters и ServletContextListener

Tags: servlet, java

Добрый день!
Внутри некоторого сервлета я определил параметры :

```
<servlet>
...
    <init-param>
        <param-name>coreProcessPoolSize</param-name>
        <param-value>1</param-value>
    </init-param>
...
</servlet>
```

Но в ServletContextListener этих параметров не видно!
Возникает вопрос, почему глобальные параметры сервлета не видны и как сделать их видимыми?

Comment: @voipp, а как вы к ним обращаетесь в сервлете?

Comment: не совсем в сервлете, но в сервисе ресурса *JAX-RS* :     

     @GET
     @Path("/LaunchServ")
     public void startLaunch(
            @QueryParam(value = "templateId") Integer templateId,
            @Context ServletContext servletContext
            ){

через инъектированную переменную.

Я на самом деле исправил ошибку, надо параметры заключить в 

     <context-param>

Но тем не менее, как достать переменные из *<init-param>*

Comment: Примерно так:

    servletContext.getInitParameter("coreProcessPoolSize");

Comment: Пишет, что не найден параметр!

Comment: А вы точно вызываете `getInitParameter` в контексте того сервлета, к которому привязан параметр?

Comment: @Nofate , да